# Buscar informação em formato de JSON de um url

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

Eu tenho uma url que quando aberta tem o seguinte `json`:

```
[ 
    { "Name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste", "City" : "Berlin", "Country" : "Germany" },
    { "Name" : "Berglunds snabbköp", "City" : "Luleå", "Country" : "Sweden" },
    { "Name" : "Centro comercial Moctezuma", "City" : "México D.F.", "Country" : "Mexico" },     
    { "Name" : "Ernst Handel", "City" : "Graz", "Country" : "Austria" }, 
    { "Name" : "FISSA Fabrica Inter. Salchichas S.A.", "City" : "Madrid", "Country" : "Spain" }, 
    { "Name" : "Galería del gastrónomo", "City" : "Barcelona", "Country" : "Spain" } 
]
```

Como eu posso pegar essa informação e coloca-la em uma string?

Comment: Esse tópico pode ajudar você: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838812/how-can-i-open-a-json-file-in-javascript-without-jquery

Comment: Pra colocar em uma string pode usar JSON.stringify(): `JSON.stringify( json )`, sendo **json** o dito cujo ou uma variável contendo algum válido.

Comment: Esse url parece estar já em string.... como estás a acessar esse url? via ajax ou a abrir a página diretamente? podes colocar o url em questão?

Answer (score 3):

Primeiro seja bem vindo ao Stackoverflow.
Como vejo que não tem experiencia com JavaScript, gostaria de tocar em certos aspectos.
O primeiro é que este tipo de pagina(conteúdo) normalamente é utilizada para permitir a comunicação entre um sistema (pode ser uma pagina) e o servidor.

Por exemplo, para que uma pagina possa ler este conteúdo, é necessário que a mesma faça uma requisição AJAX.

```
var url = "<URL com o seu JSON>";
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        var json = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        //você poderá acessar o seu objeto aqui.
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Sei que a sua pergunta foi sobre como transformar o JSON em uma string.
neste caso o proprio `xmlhttp.responseText` já é o texto a que procura.

Porém não faz sentido trabalhar com um JSON desta forma, então acredito que o que você procura é uma forma de manipular o JSON, neste caso o melhor a se fazer é deserializar a string em um Objeto, para isto basta utilizar o `JSON.parse`.

```
var json = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
```

uma vez que você recupere o json, você poderá navegar por ele.
por exemplo, caso você queira saber o nome da pessoa austriaca.

```
var name;
var contador = json.length;
for (var indice = 0; indice < contador; indice++) {
    var item = json[indice];
    if (item.Country == "Austria") {
        name = item.Name;
        break;
    }
}
console.log(name);
```

No caso acima a lista de pessoas, quando encontramos uma que pertencia a Austria, nós interrompemos busca.

Mas se já tem um objeto JSON e precisa serializar ele como texto, pode utilizar o método `JSON.stringify`

```
var serializedJSON = JSON.stringify(json);
```